# how can I add a person object to a existing class in python with a function?

Tags: python, class, append

I'm a beginner in programming with python and got stuck with the following problem:
I already made a class representing a waiting room and I want to define a function which allows me to add a new person to the list "waitinglist" e.g.:

```
def enter_room(self, person=None)

   self.waitinglist.append(person)
```

and the command would be:
person3.enter_room()

Any help what I'm missing would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please extend your question to include the complete code for the class as well as methods, as this may impact the quality of the answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear but as per my understanding something like this might be helpful.

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self):
    self.waitinglist = []
  def enter_room(self, person=None):
    self.waitinglist.append(person)
  
  def show_persons(self):
    print(self.waitinglist)

person = Person()
p1 = {"name": "Some name 1", "place": "some place 1"}
p2 = {"name": "Some name 2", "place": "some place 2"}

person.enter_room(p1)
person.enter_room(p2)

person.show_persons()
```

will output

```
[{'name': 'Some name 1', 'place': 'some place 1'}, {'name': 'Some name 2', 'place': 'some place 2'}]
```